# Celery's task_reject_on_worker_lost doesn't work with Redis as message broker

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celeryd, djcelery

I'm currently using version 5.2.6 of Celery and version 6.2.6 of Redis. When I turn on the [task_reject_on_worker_lost](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-task_reject_on_worker_lost) flag, I am expecting Celery to redeliver a task executed by a worker that died abruptly. However, trying this on Redis as message broker my task doesn't actually get redelivered immediately after a worker goes down. On the other hand, when I try the exact same configuration with RabbitMQ it works as expected.

Any pointers on how to achieve the same behavior with Redis as message broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to celery recently and facing the same issue as you did.
Which means with ack config:

```py
task_acks_late = True                       # ack after task end
task_acks_on_failure_or_timeout = True      # ack if task exception
task_reject_on_worker_lost = True           # no ack if worker killed
```

If broker config use redis:

```py
broker_url = f'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1'
```

Task will not be re queued if worker being killed during running task and restarted again.

But if use rabbitmq:

```py
broker_url = 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/'
```

Task got re queued to run.

### My environment

- linux 5.15.10-arch1-1
- python 3.8.13
- celery==5.2.7

### Finally, I found this [comment](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4984#issuecomment-782562517) from celery github issues.

Additional config value `visibility_timeout` of `broker_transport_options` is required for `redis` broker.

I added the additional config in my config and it's working.

FYI, here is my config file :

- `celery_config.py`

```py
broker_url = f'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1'
result_backend = f'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/2'

# task message ack
# https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-task_acks_late
# https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-acks-on-failure-or-timeout
# https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-reject-on-worker-lost
task_acks_late = True                       # ack after task end
task_acks_on_failure_or_timeout = True      # ack if task exception
task_reject_on_worker_lost = True           # no ack if worker killed
# only for redis broker
# https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4984
broker_transport_options = {'visibility_timeout': 10}
```

- `app.py`

```py
import celery

import celery_config

app = celery.Celery("celery")
app.config_from_object(celery_config)
```